# ¿Como puedo hacer un recorrido de una tabla html y guardar las etiquetas de esa tabla con javascript o jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, table

**Tengo una tabla en html y quiero hacer un recorrido para poder obtener y guardar las etiquetas de toda esa tabla junto con los datos de cada fila, me dijeron que puedo hacerlo con jquery o javascript; me gustaría que alguien me de una idea de como poder hacerlo espero y no sea mucha la molestia por ser tan novato en el tema**

```
<table class="table table-bordered   id="dataTable">
                        <thead style="background-color: #385ECE; color: white;">
                          <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Codigo</th>
                            <th>Proveedor</th>
                            <th>Estado</th>
                            <th>Opcion</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <div class="bodyt ">
                          <tbody style="overflow-y:visible; height:80px;">
                              <tr>
                              <td>1</td>
                              <td>PRO-00</td>
                              <td>Amilcar C</td>
                              <td>Activo</td>
                              <td>Eliminar</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                              <td>1</td>
                              <td>PRO-00</td>
                              <td>Amilcar C</td>
                              <td>Activo</td>
                              <td>Eliminar</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                              <td>1</td>
                              <td>PRO-00</td>
                              <td>Amilcar C</td>
                              <td>Activo</td>
                              <td>Eliminar</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                              <td>1</td>
                              <td>PRO-00</td>
                              <td>Amilcar C</td>
                              <td>Activo</td>
                              <td>Eliminar</td>
                            </tr>
                            
                          </tbody>
                        </div>
                      </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuidado que al principio estas poniendo el id en la class

```
class="table table-bordered   id="dataTable">
```

Lo correcto seria:

```
class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable">
```

Dándole un id a la tabla la puedes obtener en javascript atraves del método `getElementById`, lo mismo con la cabeza de la tabla (tHead), luego si quieres obtener todas las filas (rows) de la tabla puedes recorrer los hijos del el cuerpo de la tabla (tbody) con un bucle for.

Por ultimo recomiendo que veas los console.logs en el navegador tuyo, no en la ejecución del código en StackOverflow, se ve todo mas claro.

```js
'use strict'

const dataTable = document.getElementById('dataTable')
console.log('Tabla completa', dataTable)

const tHead = document.getElementById('thead')
console.log('Table Head',tHead)

const tBody = document.getElementById('tbody').children
for (let index = 0; index < tBody.length; index++) {
  const Tr = tBody[index]
  console.log(`Table Row nº ${index}`, Tr)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable">
      <thead style="background-color: #385ece; color: white">
        <tr id="thead">
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Codigo</th>
          <th>Proveedor</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>Opcion</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <div class="bodyt">
        <tbody id="tbody" style="overflow-y: visible; height: 80px">
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>PRO-00</td>
            <td>Amilcar C</td>
            <td>Activo</td>
            <td>Eliminar</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>PRO-00</td>
            <td>Amilcar C</td>
            <td>Activo</td>
            <td>Eliminar</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>PRO-00</td>
            <td>Amilcar C</td>
            <td>Activo</td>
            <td>Eliminar</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>PRO-00</td>
            <td>Amilcar C</td>
            <td>Activo</td>
            <td>Eliminar</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </div>
    </table>

    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```